# Don't break pages in between a table

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing, css-tables

As I was looking for a solution I found this: 
[Preventing Page Breaks in a Table When Printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956856/preventing-page-breaks-in-a-table-when-printin)

```
.reportTable {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

It was sad to see that it only works in opera.
Does anyone know a solution to not let tables and div's to be broken?

Also the previous asker told:

```
.reportTable {
    page-break-after: always;
}
```

Can be used but leaves a lot of useless space

Comment: Printing support in browsers generally is laughably terrible.

Comment: what if the table or div is more than a page long? How can you avoid a break inside it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try that property on the latest browsers.
Firefox seems to support it at version >= 19.0
Chrome  seems have always supported it since v1.0
Internet Explorer since v8
Opera since v7.0

Source :- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-inside

Comment: Thank you it seems its works indeed i just thougth it did not work of what i had read. in fact The code of my site was just wrong

Answer (score 0):

The page-break-inside CSS property adjusts page breaks inside the current element.

```css
/* Keyword values */
page-break-inside: auto;
page-break-inside: avoid;

/* Global values */
page-break-inside: inherit;
page-break-inside: initial;
page-break-inside: unset;
```